# How to use the HotSpot JVM @DontInline annotation?

Tags: java, inline, compiler-optimization, jvm-hotspot

I'm currently working on optimizing a particular method, which is unfortunately inlined by the JVM, which prevents it from being properly vectorized. I've noticed that there is an annotation to forbid inlining, namely `jdk.internal.vm.annotation.DontInline` . However, it cannot be accessed from the default module.

Is there a clean way of gaining access to this annotation or to prevent the inlining of the offending method some other way?

Comment: See [`-XX:CompileCommand` and `dontinline`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/unix/java.html#BABDDFII)

Comment: Yeah I'm aware of that command but it's not really something you can push to a shared repository, as far as I know.

Comment: You didn’t mention the constraint “something you can push to a shared repository” in your question. Besides that, it’s not clear why you think you can’t. Apparently, there are even more constraints you didn’t mention.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`DontInline`, `ForceInline`, etc. are JDK internal annotations, they cannot be applied to user code. Even if you somehow manage to open these annotations, HotSpot JVM has an [explicit check](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/699a3cde74eac74fb54b2ade94d437c010449f89/src/hotspot/share/classfile/classFileParser.cpp#L2108) to disallow them for non-privileged classes.

The reasons are understandable. These annotations are the implementation detail of the particular JVM version; JDK developers are free to add/remove/change meaning of such annotations without notice, even in a minor JDK update.

Using `@DontInline` to force vectorization does not seem a good approach anyway. In general, inlining should not prevent from other optimizations. If you encounter such problem, it's better to report an issue on [hotspot-compiler-dev](https://mail.openjdk.java.net/mailman/listinfo/hotspot-compiler-dev) mailing list.

---

Now the good news.

Since JDK 9, there is a public supported API to manually tune JIT compiler. This is [JEP 165: Compiler Control](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/165).

The idea is to provide compiler directives in a separate JSON file, and start the JVM with  `-XX:CompilerDirectivesFile=<file>` option. If your application is sensitive to certain compiler decisions, you may provide the directives file along with the application.

```
{
    match: "*::*",
    inline: "-org/package/MyClass::hotMethod"
}
```

It is even possible to apply compiler directives programmatically in runtime using DiagnosticCommand API:

```
ManagementFactory.getPlatformMBeanServer().invoke(
        new ObjectName("com.sun.management:type=DiagnosticCommand"),
        "compilerDirectivesAdd",
        new Object[]{new String[]{"compiler.json"}},
        new String[]{"[Ljava.lang.String;"}
);
```

By the way, there is `Vectorize: true` option among the directives list, which may probably help in vectorizing the particular method.